# How to verify that same identifier exists in two separate Cosmos-db's

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I would like to verify if records have been successfully migrated from one (source) Cosmos DB to another (destination) that's located in a separate resource group. Ideally I'd like to ensure each and every record exists within the destination given the source record identity. I cannot simply use total record count as the destination is operational and will be populated with additional records. Note: Partition key is not the id on source.

I know that we could create a change-feed for the source and (with lease set to zero) use code to reach out to the destination Cosmos DB to verify that the record exists, logging any which can't be found. This method appears heavy in terms of processing and the number of individual calls to the destination Cosmos DB. We're talking about 1M+ records.

Is there a better approach using Data Factories or another methodology that I haven't yet considered?

Comment: Have you seen this tool? It's built on change feed and has support for dead letter queuing https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-live-data-migrator

Comment: FYI resource groups really are a red-herring here (they're just grouping mechanisms, combined with some tagging and permissions). I'm assuming you have data in two separate *collections*, correct?

Comment: Yup, two separate collections. I just need to verify that everything is in place before deleting the original collection. In SQL this would take 5 seconds. In Comos DB this is apparent a little more challenging!